# Isotope filters: filter on load

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I want to show a pre-selected filter when page is loaded. Isotope filtering works quite well, filters do apply, but I don't want to see "all" when loading the page, so I'm trying to add pre-selected filter in code. What am I doing wrong?

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'click touchstart', 'section.gallery .gallery-filters .filter', function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var isotope = $( this ).parent().parent();
    var isotopeID = isotope.data( 'isotope-id' );
    var filterValue = $( this ).data( 'filter' );


    martanianLuxuryApartmentsIsotopes[isotopeID].isotope({ filter: filterValue });

    isotope.find( '.gallery-filters' ).children( '.filter' ).removeClass( 'filter-active' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'filter-active' );

            //SHOW THE SELECTED FILTER
    isotope({
    itemSelector: '.filter',
    filter: '.gallery-filter-building'
    });

    isotope.find( '.gallery-single-image' ).removeClass( 'isotope-element-visible' );
    var filteredElements = martanianLuxuryApartmentsIsotopes[isotopeID].isotope( 'getFilteredItemElements' );
    for( var i = 0; i < filteredElements.length; i++ ) {

        var filteredElement = $( filteredElements[i] );
        filteredElement.addClass( 'isotope-element-visible' );

    };

});
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you use this

```
$(function() {
   //all code isotope here
});
```

or equal

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //all code isotope here
});
```

this way all inside that function is executed when page is load.